# Python summing values including "nan" and finding clustering error

Tags: python, loops, cluster-analysis, distance, nan

I am almost new in Python. In clustering problem, suppose we have k clusters. I wanted to find sum of errors between points of clusters from their centers.

Here is my distance function to find sum of distance of groups of points (i.e. g) from a reference point p.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
def distgp(g,p):
    dist = sum(scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(g,p)) 
    return dist

# Now I am going to find sum of errors of clusters.
f = 0
for i in range(k): 
    ix = LabelX==i 
    if any(ix):
         f+=distgp(X[ix,:],X[ix,:].mean(axis=0)[:,None].T)
```

Here X is a dataset with almost 500000 observations and LabelX is cluster labels for points. Sometimes `X[ix,:]` is empty so the `X[ix,:].mean(axis=0)` is empty (RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice), that is why I used "if any(ix)" to just consider nonempty ones.

The time is very important to me. The code works but I think there should be some efficient way for the function distgp and the loop to find sum of errors. I would appreciate your comments on improving the code in terms of speed.

Thanks, 
Sam

Comment: python's list comprehensions are written in C and are much faster than for loops. [link](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Comment: also what is that line `ix = LabelX==i` doing? It seems like it should just be `ix=i`, but in that case, why even have it?

Comment: ix = LabelX==i finds all rows indices where points belongs to ith cluster, where LabelX is the cluster labeling for dataset X (similar to kmeans.labels_). Then I find distances of those points from their mean ( i.e. X[ix,:].mean(axis=0) ) using distgp function.